# How to access the string of the cell I am typing?

Tags: front-end, keyboard, web-access

I'm trying to map a keyboard shortcut to google search the contents of the cell I am typing. Here is my code so far:

```
MenuItem["Google",
       FrontEndExecute[{FrontEnd`SelectionMove[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], Cell, FrontEnd`InputCell],
       KernelExecute[
        $myContent = FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[]]];
        $myContent = $myContent[[1,1]];
        googleSearch[$myContent];
    ]}],
    MenuKey["l", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}], MenuEvaluator -> "Local"]

googleSearch[search_String] := SystemOpen["https://www.google.com/#q="<>URLEncode[search]]
```

Note: I don't want to have to select the cell with my mouse first. I'm thinking of using the FE token "ExpandSelection".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was right using ExpandSelection twice does the trick, but not the prettiest answer, but anyway, just add this to MenuSetup.tr:

```
MenuItem["Google",
FrontEndExecute[{
FrontEndTokenExecute["ExpandSelection"],
FrontEndTokenExecute["ExpandSelection"],
KernelExecute[
    $myContent = FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookRead[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[]]];
    googleSearch[$myContent[[1]]];
]}],
MenuKey["l", Modifiers -> {"Control", "Shift"}], MenuEvaluator -> "Local"],
```